# How to show an iPhone message (alert?) that looks like the one is shown when you toggle silent mode

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

When you toggle an iPhone to/from silent mode, or when you adjust the volume by pressing the side buttons, there is an icon that appears in the middle of the screen. Does Cocoa Touch allow developers to use this style of alert? If so, what's it called?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out [`MBProgressHUD`](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)

It's actually a replica of undocumented, private iOS code called UIProgressHUD.

Comment: Is there not a native way to do this? or at least a framework?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a progressHUD, but more of a StatusHUD. see here for a good one: https://github.com/samvermette/SVStatusHUD

Like sam (the creator of StatusHUD) says:

> SVStatusHUD mimics the HUD shown on orientation lock, mute and volume change on iOS. It should only be used in response to hardware or other important notifications (for instance when an accessory is detected by your app). If you’re just looking to show the progress or success of an operation, you should have a look at SVProgressHUD.

Comment: Is there not a native way to do this? or at least a framework?

Comment: No, Apple has their own private API. But they're really not complex 3rd party libs (look at the source).

Answer (score 1):

Please note that you should not use private API like the UIProgressHUD or Apple will reject your app when you submit it. I recommend that you build your own design by manipulating a view and adding it as a subview, or use a free library that does so. If you do your own view (as I do in my apps) you can easily show it and hide it by playing with the alpha property. Here is an example:

First create a NIB file and design it as you like. Remember to re-size it (say to 260*200 or anything you like) so it looks like a notification. Add the components you want to it and give them Tags so you can access them later. Assume in my example that I only added a `UILabel`.

In the view that you would like to use your custom notification, create a `UIView` object in the .h file (here I call it `pleaseWait`) and in the .m file (usually in the `viewDidLoad`) load it as follows:

```
NSArray *nibMyNiceAlert = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"myNiceAlertNibName" owner:self options:nil];
((UILabel*)[[nibMyNiceAlert objectAtIndex:0] viewWithTag:1]).text = NSLocalizedString(@"The text the user will see", @"my explanation of this text!");
pleaseWait = [nibConnecting objectAtIndex:0];
pleaseWait.frame = CGRectMake(30, 70, 260, 200);
pleaseWait.alpha = 0;
pleaseWait.clipsToBounds = YES;
pleaseWait.layer.cornerRadius = 20;
[self.view addSubview:pleaseWait];
```

Note that `clipsToBounds` and `cornerRadius` need the library `QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h` and are used to make the edges of your view rounded. Notice that the alpha starts 0 because I don't want to see my alert on load.

Now every time you would like to show this notification:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"FadeIn" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
pleaseWait.alpha = 0.65;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

And to remove it:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"FadeOut" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
pleaseWait.alpha = 0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Remember that you can change the text in the notification label anytime before you view it by acceding the object at Tag 1 as I did in the loading stage.

I hope this helps yo in a way.